# how to use set offscreen page limit in bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-volley, bottomnavigationview

I'm using a navigation bottom with 5 fragments.

Each fragment makes HTTP call and downloads content, but while replacing the fragment the view is destroyed and downloads it again.

In my search I found out that I should use setOffscreenPageLimit this method
but I don't use viewpager.

How could I implement something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing fragments, add fragments to the fragment manager and show/hide them.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    addFragmentsToManager();
}

private void addFragmentsToManager() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
              fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flContent, tripFragment, 
             tripFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flContent, notificationFragment, 
             notificationFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flContent, searchFragment, 
             searchFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flContent, profileFragment, 
             profileFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

   fragmentTransaction.hide(tripFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.hide(searchFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void changeTab(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
        fragment = .....// get framgnet from position
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
               fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, 
               R.anim.fade_out);

    fragmentTransaction.hide(prvFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment).commit();
    prvFragment = fragment;
}
```